# Regarding Godel's arithmetic technique in Incompleteness Theorem.

Tags: incompleteness

This question is about the number system Godel used in his Incompleteness Theorem.  It seems that the result of his theorem is that somethings (in mathematics) may never be provable, although they will still be true.  I was listening to a lecture regarding the theorem and the presenter made the comment that during the number-encoding step the theorem was essentially transforming into a meta-language, which was outside the original symbol based language that the theorem is constructed in.

My understanding is that somethings may be proved when in a different meta-language if they are not provable in the language in which they are first modeled.

My question is this; if the G statement cannot be proved in the original language and axioms from where it is constructed, is the act of transforming the statement into Godel numbering what allows it to become provable?  Is the proof happening in the arithmetic phase of the proof because that is a meta-language somehow where the proof can take place?  Then do the results decode back into symbols to show that the statement is in fact true?  I hope my question is clear.

Comment: Hello, you should watch this excellent video from the Veritasium channel : https://youtu.be/HeQX2HjkcNo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"It seems that the result of [Gödel's] theorem is that some things (in mathematics) may never be provable". Not so. It is the result of Gödel's theorem that for any suitable theory $T$, there will be a sentence $G_T$ that $T$ itself can't decide -- i.e. $T$ itself can't prove $G_T$ and $T$ can't prove $\neg G_T$. But that leaves it wide open that $G_T$ can be proved in some other way, perhaps in some natural expansion of $T$ or in some other theory.

It can help to shift focus for a moment from the standardly constructed *Gödel sentence* $G_T$ for a suitable given theory $T$ to the consistency sentence $Con(T)$ (which roughly says that no number codes for a $T$-proof of absurdity). It will be fairly elementarily provable inside $T$ that $G_T \equiv Con(T)$. So we have the second incompleteness result: assuming it is consistent, $T$ can't prove $Con(T)$ or $\neg Con(T)$. But that leaves it wide open that $Con(T)$ can be proved in some other way. For a simple example, standard first-order arithmetic $PA$ is incomplete -- it can't prove $Con(PA)$. But we believe that $PA$ *is* consistent. And, if we like, we can prove $PA$ is consistent in some richer theory like a weak set theory. So we think $Con(PA)$ is true. And, a further step, our reasons for thinking it true can be formalised in our richer set theory which can then prove the arithmetical coding of the claim in the form $Con(PA)$.

Now, varying your question just a bit: "if the $Con(PA)$ statement cannot be proved in the original language and axioms from where it is constructed, is the act of transforming the statement into Godel numbering what allows it to become provable"? No. That rather gets things upside down. It is trick of "transforming" the claim PA-is-consistent into a formal arithmetical statement via Gödel numbering which enables us to construct the formal statement $Con(PA)$ and which is used in showing that it can't be proved in the relevant theory $T$. On the other hand, what makes PA-is-consistent true, and provably true in a richer context, need not involve any Gödel numbering (that will only come back into the picture if we also want to show that one particular way of expressing that, namely $Con(PA)$, is also provable in the richer context).

For more see e.g. my *Gödel Without (Too Many) Tears*, downloadable from https://logicmatters.net/igt

Comment: That is very helpful and concise, thank you.  If I may press a little further.  There are two ways my mind is trying to resolve this, and I'm prepared to accept that they are both wrong, but I'd like to ask about them to see if they are useful.  In a way it seems like the proof Godel designed is showing that the G statement is not provable.  I believe that means it is undecidable and therefore it cannot be shown to be true or false.  Because he proved that, it turns out the statement is true, because that is what it claims.  This proof relies on an undecidable outcome.

Comment: The other possibility that I see is that his proof actually shows that the G statement is true.  That being the case, we can interpret the result as showing that the claim of the statement is true; and we see that it is unprovable.  This relies on a true result to his proof.  This second interpretation makes me more uncomfortable as it seems more like a paradox.  Is either of these explanations close to how the proof works.  I apologize as these are semantic interpretations so I don't think they can really fit with the actual proof.

Comment: Neither is quite right. I suggest you take a look at a good exposition of Gödel's theorems which should clear things up. I've already mentioned one. But Chap 6 of the *Beginning Mathematical Logic* Study Guide downloadable at https://logicmatters.net/tyl will point you to some quite excellent alternatives

Comment: Thank you for the material and direction.  Very much appreciated.  Cheers.